# How can I fix a loud buzzing sound while dishwasher is running?

Tags: dishwasher

Kenmore Dishwasher is making a loud buzz while the dishwasher is running - it stops when the motor stops/water drains.

Here is an audio file of the sound: https://recorder.google.com/50b37bc7-a208-4ab2-aa23-1bfb4f978412

Dishes appear to be getting clean.

Is this something I can fix?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a _new_ sound, or has it always been like that and is finally annoying enough to want to do something about it? If it's new, it could be that the pump is failing (by any number of failure paths). Replacing the pump _might_ just fix the problem.

Comment: Yeah. New sound. Maybe time to replace it.

Comment: I wonder if something outside the tub has come into contact with something else, causing a resonance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Maytag started doing that when the circulation pump failed. You have two pumps in typical dishwashers--the circulation pump and the drain. The big one at the center is the former.

I tried replacing just the pump and not the whole bottom plate of mine. That seemed to work but got noisy again before long--something adjacent to the motor must've been failing instead, or *also*. Since I had actually purchased the entire plate assembly (it was cheaper than just the pump), I then dismounted and replaced the whole thing, putting the new motor back on.

That has worked well for several months of daily use. It's a more complex project than replacing individual parts, but mostly involved pulling the unit out and flipping it over, then unclipping the securing levers to free the plate. Plug-n-play, really. Clean up the primary seal well so it continues to do its job.